# How many elements does the set of units contains?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Given $\langle X^6+X^3+1\rangle \in \mathbb{F}_2[X]$ is an irreducible polynomial, let's define $R:= \mathbb{F}_2[X]/ \langle X^6+X^3+1 \rangle$

- How much elements does R contain?

  $R$ contains $2^6=64$ elements
- How many elements does the set of units contain?

Here, I know that every non zero element is either a zero divisor or a unit, but since $X^6+X^3+1$ is irreducible, $R$ is a field and therefore there are no zerodivisor, but still, how do I know how many elements?

- What is the multiplicative order of the element $X + \langle X^6+X^3+1\rangle$?

I was thinking about reasoning as follow:
(but not sure exactly what to do)

$X^0=1$

$X^1=X$

$X^2=X^2$

$X^3=X^3$

$X^4=X^4$

$X^5=X^5$

$X^6=[-X^3-1]$

...

Any clue for this point, please ?

EDIT:

$X^6=[-X^3-1]$

$X^9=X^3[-X^3-1]=[-X^6-X^3]=-1$

$X^{15}=-X^6=[X^3+1]$

$X^{18}=X^3[X^3+1]=[X^6+X^3]=1$

Comment: For the third question, it's best to take powers and every time you have a power of that is at least $6$, replace it with $X^3+1$.

Comment: You know $R$ is a field, so its multiplicative group has order $63$. Therefore you only need to try factors of $63$ for its order.

Comment: Are you referring to the second question?

Comment: Remember 1 = -1

Comment: Of course,thanks! So 9 is the order!